# Setup checkboxes when page is loaded

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I try to setup checkboxes and cannot get working simple code.

Any clue?

Thank you!

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Web Reports - Peliculas";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
            var name = $(this).attr('name'); // grab name of original
            var value = $(this).attr('value'); // grab value of original

            alert(name); // It doesn't work at all :(
        });
    })​;
});
</script>
```

=================== UPDATE =============================

Generated code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MySite</title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link href="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18/css/flick/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18/development-bundle/ui/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>

      <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18/development-bundle/ui/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-es.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#startDate").keyup(function () {
                $('#endDate').val($('#startDate').val());
            });
        });


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div id="header">
            <div class="user">
                    <span style="text-align: right;">Bienvenido, <strong>mobile
                    </strong>! <a href="/Home/LogOff">LogOff</a></span>
            </div>
            <div id="title" style="display: table-row; vertical-align: top;">
                <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;">
                    <a href="/">
                        <img src="/Images/b-default.jpg" width="370px"  alt=""  /></a>
                </div>
                <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 100%;">
                    <h1 style="text-align: right;">
                        Web Reports</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <div class="clear">
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {


        $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
            var name = $(this).attr('name'); // grab name of original
            var value = $(this).attr('value'); // grab value of original

            alert(name);
        });


})​;
    });
</script>
<h2>
```

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML?

Comment: Have you included jQuery javascript file?

Comment: @fredrik Yes I have it included.

Comment: The javascript works fine with checkboxes in static HTML. Are the checkboxes shown in the screen?

Comment: @David Pls Have a look at generated code. I just updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an erroneous `})` in your code try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
            var name = $(this).attr('name'); 
            var value = $(this).attr('value'); 

            alert(name); 
        });
     // })​;
});
```

As a *sidenote* you can use the `val()` method for getting/setting the value of checkboxes:

```
var value = $(this).val();
```

Comment: U are extremely right man! Thanks!!!!!